# sfdx force:source:pull -> Entity of type 'AuthProvider' named '' cannot be found

Tags: salesforcedx, oauth2, namedcredentials, auth-provider

I am trying to do a `sfdx force:source:pull` from a scratch org where I defined and authenticated a **Named Credential** and **Auth Provider** (OAuth2 Named Principal). I get:

> • RetrieveFailed - Entity of type 'AuthProvider' named 'MyProvider'
>   cannot be found

The only thing that I have found was this [Known Issue: Metadata cannot be pulled after first authentication with Lightning for GMail](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000JWYJQA4) without any workaround.

Comment: Not sure if you really want to pull the metadata, otherwise you could skip the complaining file by adding them to [.forceignore](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm)

Comment: How would I do that for this case? Add **AuthProvider or **NamedCredential there?

Comment: Either that or its complaining about file named `A360 Keycloak`, you may need to do few tries.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to selectively pull the problematic metadata using this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rohanatgwcs/sfdx-selective-retrieve-deploy

```
sfdx gs:source:pull --type AuthProvider --names MyProvider --targetdir force-app/main/default/authProvider
```

Comment: Appear to be getting this issue again. Using API version 53.0.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure your AuthProvider name has no spaces.

I was able to pull the metadata using the retrieve command:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m AuthProvider
```

However, your subsequent pull commands will continue to fail because it cannot find the AuthProvider.

If you rename it replacing spaces with underscores (Name and URL Suffix will both have no special chars) pull commands will work just fine.

Hope this helps.

Jose